# Can we create multiple users for single neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I want to create multiple users to access single neo4j database with each user having their own database location. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j doesn't support that, but there is 3rd party solution for that.

[Securing Neo4j with GraphAware Enterprise](http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/03/29/securing-neo4j-with-graphaware-enterprise.html)

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j does not yet have a concept if simultaneously run multiple databases out of a single installation.

Just install Neo4j multiple times, change the port numbers in the config files appropriately.

Alternatively run the docker image multiple times in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE 
(a:Person {name: 'Joe'}),
(b:Person {name: 'Jill'}),
(c:Person {name: 'Jack'}),
(d:Person {name: 'John'}),
(e:Person {name: 'Jane'}),
(f:Person {name: 'Janice'}) 
RETURN a,b,c,d,e,f;
```

**This can be done in for loop with java or Python, and if you talking about really big data then take a look at it. the CSV file (import data)**

*Maybe this is not a solution But definitely one of the ways.*